# Substring \ in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to substring but getting exception throwing.

```
 my string  "currentUserLogin" is uponet\\xyz
```

so what I want final result is xyz

```
string currentUser = currentUserLogin.Substring(currentUserLogin.LastIndexOf("'\'"));
```

Comment: Too many quotes. You only need the single quotes

Comment: What exception are you getting? Why don' t you post it here?

Comment: it doesn't work with single! i guess that is why is throwing error

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't explain what problem you're seeing in that case *or* what problem you're seeing now...

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
string currentUser = currentUserLogin.Substring(currentUserLogin.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
```

I should also point out that you will want some actual error handling. This will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if the \ comes at the very end of the string.

Relevant documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: that returns a \xyz wierd, since we ask for the last ?

Comment: Cool :) and no, no error just tested, indexes is zero based so and the substring is not, it uses the actual posiotion in the string 1,2,3 etc. so adding the 1 effectively converts it :) ... just had to test it my self

Answer (score 2):

Safer way to do it is to check if it is in the string first, or check if `index > -1`.

```
int index = currentUserLogin.LastIndexOf('\\');
if (index > -1)
{
    if (index + 1 == currentUserLogin)
    {
        currentUser = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        currentUser = currentUserLogin.SubString(index + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is probably more desirable than catching an exception. There is overhead that comes with exception handling.  See post on C# try/catch overhead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312/what-is-the-real-overhead-of-try-catch-in-c

Comment: This will still throw an exception if the \ is at the end of the string.

Comment: True, I'll add a test for this

Answer (score 1):

This here works like a charm

```
        string currentUserLogin = "uponet\\xyz"; //Login
        string[] currentUserParts = currentUserLogin.Split('\\');// splits in parts of [uponet],[],[xyz]
        string currentUser = currentUserParts[currentUserParts.Count() - 1]; // get last from array
```

\ is a escape charector so by it standing a lone the compiler dont know what to do with it, the correct way to use e.g:

- \r that is a new line
- \\ that translate to \

and so forth

Hope this helps :)